# repr() output different in IDLE and Windows Powershell

Tags: python-2.7, powershell, python-idle, repr

Executing `python ex1.py` with `ex1.py` contents: `print repr('foo')` yields

`'foo'`

But executing `repr('foo')` on IDLE yields

`"'foo'"`

Alternatively, executing `print repr('foo')` on IDLE yields

`'foo'`

And executing `python ex1.py` with `ex1.py` contents: `repr('foo')` clearly yields

`\n`

For the former three cases...what's going on here?

Comment: if you ran `print repr('foo')` in IDLE you would get the same results as running it anywhere else, typing stuff into the interactive console shows the `repr` of the result so you are essentially seeing `repr(repr('foo'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repr('foo')` is an expression whose value is the 5-character string `'foo'`.

Therefore:

1. Printing the result of `repr('foo')` will display `'foo'`.
2. Typing `repr('foo')` in a Python interpreter (such as IDLE's shell) will show the repr of `'foo'`, which is `"'foo'"`.
3. Running a Python script containing just the code `repr('foo')` won't print anything, so you just get an empty output (the `\n` is likely added by your shell).

Answer (score 1):

repr() - Return a string containing a printable representation of an object.

The output of `print repr('foo')` is `'foo'`.

When you run it from the shell you get the output with-in quotes(string) => `"'foo'"`

When you run `print repr('foo')` from a python script you get the out string printed as => `'foo'`

When you just put `repr('foo')` in your script you get nothing as you don't have a print statement to print the output.